# What is the best approach to run CRON jon and GCP Cloud SQL Proxy in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, proxy, cron, cloud-sql-proxy

I hope y'all doing great!

I came to a hard time looking for the best way to solve this problem in my project, and finally, I've collected my courage to post this question in Stackoverflow (please don't bully me).

I have a cron job that runs the job for a quite long time to complete the task and this cron job needs a connection to db, so I'm using cloud-sql-proxy.

Currently, I'm using the Kubernetes sidecar pattern, where the cron is the main image and the cloud-sql-proxy image is the side image.

My problem currently is, when my cron job is completed, the cloud-sql-proxy is still running, I tried using this approach https://cotton-ori.medium.com/how-to-terminate-a-side-car-container-in-kubernetes-job-2468f435ca99 where once the cron is completed I kill the cloud-sql-proxy process. But since cloud-sql-proxy image is not allowing other than cloud-sql-proxy executeable anymote, I couldn't implement this approach.

Does anyone here have solution for this problem where

1. Cron job wait for the cloud-sql-proxy to be ready
2. Once the cloud-sql-proxy is ready, run the cron job
3. once the cron job is completed, also stop the cloud-sql-proxy
4. The kubernetes pod is completed.

Thank you for your answers. Hope Y'all have a good day!